# How to determine which category an Excel cell value falls into?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm dealing with percentiles. Let me break it down:

the 50th %ile thresholds: 71.93%

the 75th %ile thresholds: 78.93%

the 90th %ile thresholds: 83.93%

I'm tracking rates for a health measure. I want to create a cell that changes the percentile score every time a provider exceeds the score.

For example, this week let's say John Doe has a score of 71.29% I would want the 50th %ile score to display in the cell below. The next week let's say he exceeds the 50th %ile thresholds score of 71.93%. I would want the 75th %ile thresholds to populate since that is his next goal.

I tried combining three if statements.

Comment: Use this as a helper to post sample data: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables# also share what you tried, instead of saying it.

Comment: Could you show readers the `IF` statements that you tried? It sounds like the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to do this, and selecting which one often comes down to which version of Excel you have.  For O365, use `XMATCH()` which gets it all done in one step.  In earlier versions, use `INDEX(MATCH())`.

For the examples:

- Assume John Doe’s score is in cell A1, and you want to display the percentile in A2 underneath it.
- For the purposes of this illustration, assume the 4 values are located in D1:D4.  There will be four instead of three because of the way we find the right value.  What do you want display if John Doe’s value is > 83.93%?  In my illustration I assume that anything over 83.93% should display 100%, but that is just my assumption.
- The percentiles must be entered in ascending order:

`D1` = 71.93%

`D2` = 78.93%

`D3` = 83.93%

`D4` = 100%

With those assumptions in mind:

***In O365***

In Cell `A2`, enter:

`=XMATCH( A1, $D$1:$D$4, 1 )`

***In non-O365 Versions***

In Cell `A2`, enter:

`=INDEX( $D$1:$D$4, MATCH( A1, $D$1:$D$4, -1 ) )`